# What is the lighter area of the today pane?

Tags: ios, widgets

I noticed there’s a lighter area in the today pane on iOS. Some widgets will only live in that area, and some others just in the area outside. **It seems there are two kinds of widgets.** Why is this so?

In the images below the first widget (weather) is of one type and can only be placed outside of the lighter (on dark mode darker) area. The other widget can only be placed in it.

[image]

After haptic touching the today pane, one can edit the two kinds of widgets in different ways: the first kind by clicking the + and the second kind by clicking `Anpassa` (edit).

[image]

The lighter area is for one kind of widgets, it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom area of the Today view is for iOS 8 widgets.
The upper area is for the newer iOS 16 widgets.

iOS 16 widgets are

- built with SwiftUI's [WidgetKit framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/creating-a-widget-extension/)

  > Widgets elevate a small amount of timely, personally relevant information from your app, display it where people can see it at a glance, and offer specific app functionality without launching the app. On iPhone and iPad, people put widgets in Today View, on the Home Screen, and on the Lock Screen.
- more efficient on battery
- didn't support interactivity until iOS 17
- can be placed on the home screen

iOS 8 widgets are

- built with the [Notification Center framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/notificationcenter)

  > The Notification Center framework helps you create and manage app extensions that implement Today widgets. The framework provides an API you can use to specify whether a Today widget has content to display, and to customize aspects of its appearance and behavior.
- able to support greater interactivity
- only able to be placed on the lower section of the today view
- deprecated by Apple

Since developers are required to rebuild their widgets to the iOS 16 framework, iOS still supports the older widgets in the lower section of the Today view.